# Typescript Template Literals convert array to a list

Tags: typescript

I have an array:

```
 const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

That I want to convert to a comma-separated list - `'a,b,c'`. Is there any way to convert it's type also using the new [Template Literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) feature?

```
function toList<T>(arr: T[]) {
  return arr.join(',')
}

const list: 'a,b,c' = toList(arr);
```

Comment: What do u mean? It's a type question. I want the list variable to be typed as I wrote.

Comment: I upvoted it, don't understand why it was downvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;

type Arr = typeof arr;

type Elem = string
type Mapper<
  Arr extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>,
  Result extends string = ''
  > = Arr extends []
  ? Result
  : Arr extends [infer H]
  ? H extends Elem
  ? `${Result},${H}`
  : never
  : Arr extends readonly [infer H, ...infer Tail]
  ? Tail extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>
  ? H extends Elem
  ? Result extends '' ? Mapper<Tail, `${Result}${H}`> : Mapper<Tail, `${Result},${H}`>
  : never
  : never
  : never;

type Result = Mapper<Arr> //  "a,b,c"


function toList<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>>(arr: T) {
  return arr.join(',') as Mapper<T>
}

const list = toList(arr);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gcjpgNDTAIzwOEwF14IZRIoBuAKEagE8AHAUxgEElUYbLiABm8JExYduAUQA2nALYDoCAJZgA5lK4wAsnHZcEAHkYxe-TgA8onMABNqAJU5wH4Oaz4I4rE-JKAHy45jCuEACucrA2do7UqhqaApiYYUECPjBx9k4Y5GEA-OGcUTFhAFyWyLkJGBoinMgAEoUWJS05tnnUgYrFMAAGACQA3hHRUAC%20uOMt00NVMGCcAG7Ny9l1%20QhuHmBeDWBNrfgAdJeNzTAAKnBqcu0wJfeP3fH5ru6e3kh%20AQUiiCgy6Oz6QMGkxiH16BEwL30hmMJjecnwowmZSm03mi0y1QMRmaqIe6OG42hMzmYwWQxBFmqqw2CGWzM2jJW62akiE3CpAiJKJ8mQA9KKLAAiOC4Qi4YCS5iMESRMDAKBqcCCEAAGTU0FRsPq3wOXh8AKSWiCQQAFIgENVbgBKGBjMJ7KCRBBgcQIc4AKxAGhteEwLrg1CFJNuIOmzFo0Bgcn1sDQUF1KbtSCd9CAA)

[Here](https://catchts.com/tuples#reduce) you can find more interesting examples

P.S. Please, keep in mind, it is not 100% type safe because I used casting operator `as`

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the [captain-yossarian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495254/captain-yossarian) example to extends ReadonlyArray interface.
This approcach avoid cast statement.

```
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;

type Join<
  List extends ReadonlyArray<string>,
  Seperator extends string = ',',
  Joined extends string = ''
  > = List extends []
  ? Joined
  : List extends [infer Head]
  ? Head extends string
  ? `${Joined}${Seperator}${Head}`
  : never
  : List extends readonly [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? Tail extends ReadonlyArray<string>
  ? Head extends string
  ? Joined extends '' ? Join<Tail, Seperator, `${Joined}${Head}`> : Join<Tail, Seperator, `${Joined}${Seperator}${Head}`>
  : never
  : never
  : never;

interface ReadonlyArray<T extends string> {
  join<Separator extends string, This extends ReadonlyArray<T>>(this: This, separator: Separator): Join<This, Separator>
}

const joined = list.join(',')
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDA2gcgIaYDQyYBG+hwmAujNhDKJFANwBQzUAngA4CmMAUiARgAPMxgwAMkljcAHlG5gAJrQBK3bEvBx2AQQBO+7O2HR9QgOYA+PGJgBlbjyNQQ+mHIXLaZy6kJ4+HYCQtxKHvKKKjC+YBb+mJh2Vv5SyJ5RtOgUdgD8-IJgYXYAXJLSEV7R6EIAZtzuABIaSjni+c2alZkxUOZxeTAABgAkAN4hRUoAvuOOztiu+rNjnTNDpTBFAG4Nm2kykd4w+i3a7Bh1DTBrBAB0D1fuACrYCHBtMPmv793H6ppzgYjCZYtZBms-tEwYNJmEobREl8CkJhD84AR5g1Fm4CKMJoUwis1tMhikypM0W8MQ4nNilnjxnCZnM6S43MSWqSrJsdntxGU+fpedxdvoWMwhAp9LVsMBeACtGAdMDjGiEb1+tYYGM7AArQrCebYdnuDLHMEEZ4ACyQGsVQMMaueVisAAooLaIGUbUgCBAnCacfoysbTQBKCmG30QTGB0086asejIA2hcJoRDQO5psBu-CYcPMIA)